Basic definition of header files
What exactly is a header file (in C)? I'm new to coding so I wanted to know a simple definition.
I searched up on google but I couldn't find a definition which I could actually understand. also are there any other header files, if yes, do they all serve different purposes?

What do your beginners material (books, tutorials, classes) say about it?

Pay close attention to the word "declaration" used in the answers and understand how that differs from the "definition". A declaration and definition need not appear at the same place in any file. A declaration (e.g. int myfunction (int);) simply declares myfunction() and promises it is defined somewhere later on. int myfunction (int a) { return a * a; } defines the function. Since all declarations must appear before they are used, a header is a convenient place to present all function declarations together -- even though they may be defined later or elsewhere.

The Definitive C Book Guide and List

The C Standard doesn't define the term "header file". It says what a header is (and emphasizes that a header is not necessarily a file).
A header is a place where the implementation declares functions, types, macros, and associated facilities from the C Standard library. The exact nature of that place is not specified in the Standard. It could be a file that comes with the implementation, or it could be a compiler built-in, or an entry in a database, or anything else. Headers are identified by name. For example, <stdio.h> is a header name.
Colloquially, user-written source files (commonly with names ending in an .h suffix) meant to be included in other source files via the #include preprocessor directive, are also called headers. This is non-standard terminology. The C Standard just calls them source files.

What is standard function? If my header contains function prototype void foo(void); will it be a "standard" function?

@0___________ A standard function is a library function specified by the Standard, such as printf. Reworded to avoid ambiguities.

Re “A header is a place where the implementation declares… Colloquially, user-written source files… are also called headers. This is non-standard terminology.”: No, a header is not a place where only the implementation declares things, and it is not colloquial or non-standard to use “header” for files (or whatever is used for headers) supplied by the user. The standard refers to the standard-specified and implementation-supplied headers as “standard headers” and uses “header” or “headers” for headers generally at multiple places throughout the standard.

@EricPostpischil Perhaps there is a couple of places where the Standard does that (it is not very consistent), but I find that "header" and "standard header" are henerally used as synonyms in the Standard. A "header name" can map to either a header (== "a standard header") or to a source file, and the standard consistently distinguishes between the two, see e.g. 6.4.8/2, 5.2.1.2/1, 6.10.2/6.

The word “header” does not appear in 6.4.8 paragraph 2, 5.2.1.2 1, or 6.10.2 6 in the C 2018 standard, the C 2023 N3096 draft, the C 2011 N1570 draft, the C 2007 N1256 draft, or the C 1999 standard.

@EricPostpischil I am usung https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3301.pdf

Draft N3301 6.4.8 2 uses “headers” to refer to any kind of headers; it is not a reference only to standard headers. Here and throughout, the standard uses “header” or “header name” versus “source file” or “source file names” because it allows for the possibility that headers (standard or user) may be implemented as something other than files, not because it is distinguishing standard headers from user headers. 5.2.1.2 1 follows this; its reference to processing headers and source files for #include directives includes standard and user headers. So does 6.10.2 6.
